# social business cloud community get request incorrect responses

Tags: ibm-connections

I want to show a feed of all communities in the social business cloud environment in my application and since I don't want to use any basic authentication in my program I'm using the oAuth protocol.

Sadly using the oAuth accesstoken in the following url returns me different search results. 50% of the requests leave out certain communities.
This is the URL I am using.

```
"Domain"/communities/service/atom/communities/all?ps=1000
```

Why is this happening and is there a solution to this problem?